# What decides javascript type conversion order?

Tags: javascript

Assume a simple sample

```
let a = [] + [];
```

In this, both `[]` are converted to empty strings, so the result `a` is empty string too.

Now, take for example,

```
let a = null + "";
```

This coerces a to `"null"`.

From the above two samples, it seems like the + operator converts the arguments to strings( otherwise `null + ""` should've returned 0).

But if we do

```
let a = null + null;
```

The value of `a`, which is expected to be `"nullnull"`, is actually `0`, so my question is what is the order of type let a = null + "";in JS?

Answer (score 0):

null + "" returns "null" because null gets converted to string.

In the second example, it does not get converted to string because it is not necessary( there are no strings involved in that assignment)

instead, null's get converted to a number( which is 0 )
so a = 0 + 0

The order of type coersion is defined by brackets or left to right.

```
e.g 
1) "" + null + null // "nullnull"
2) "" + (null + null) // "0"
3)  null + null + "x" // "0x"
4) "x" + null + null // "xnullnull"
```

Answer (score 0):

If any of the operands in the expression are castable into a string, then + operator will do a string concatenation (and will covert all other operands to string). If no operands are castable to string, then + operator will do a number addition.

In your first example empty array is an aboject and is castable to string so `[] + []` yields `""`. Just like if you do `[1, 2] + [3, 4]` gives you `"1,23,4"` as casting array to string yields a comma separated list of its elements.

Your second example with empty string and null is working in this way because you have a string in the expression, so all other operands (null in this case) gets converted into a string.

The third example of adding two null's is giving you 0 because the expression does not have an operand castable into a string, so number addition takes place and because converting null to number yields 0 therefore 0 + 0 = 0.